# JsonArray object serialization using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, .net, json.net

I have JSON object in below format.

```json
[
   {
      "checked":true,
      "discipline":"Registered Nurse",
      "disciplineId":1,
      "specialty":"OR",
      "specialtyId":7
   },
   {
      "checked":true,
      "discipline":"Registered Nurse",
      "disciplineId":1,
      "specialty":"Ambulatory OR",
      "specialtyId":62
   },
   {
      "checked":true,
      "discipline":"Registered Nurse",
      "disciplineId":1,
      "specialty":"Pedi-OR",
      "specialtyId":101
   }
]
```

I would like to map the properties in below format using C#. JSON object is coming through `Reader`.

```
jobPreferencesEvent.preferred_discipline =
    reader["discipline"] != DBNull.Value ? reader["discipline"].ToString() : "0";

jobPreferencesEvent.preferred_specialty =
    reader["speciality"] != DBNull.Value ? reader["speciality"].ToString() : "0";
```

Could someone help me on it?

Comment: first create a class with those properties... then use newtonsoft

Comment: What type is `Reader`?  What type is `Jsonarray`?  What library are you currently using to read your JSON?  You have tagged your question [tag:json.net] but Json.NET does not have a `Jsonarray` type (it has `JArray` instead), and LINQ-to-JSON objects will generally not contain `DBNull.Value`, which leads me to suspect you are not actually using Json.NET.  A [mcve] showing fully how to reproduce your problem (including any necessary includes and nuget packages) would help us to help you; see [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try out:

```
jobPreferencesEvent.preferred_discipline = reader.GetString(1)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).